# How is G derived from this formula?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit stumped. I've stumbled upon these formulas for converting $RGB$ to $YC_BC_R$ color space...:

$$Y=a*R+b*G+c*B$$
$$C_B=\frac{B-Y}d$$
$$C_R=\frac{R-Y}e$$

...and back again...:

$$R =Y+e*C_R$$
$$G =Y-\Bigl(\frac{a*e}b\Bigr)*C_R-\Bigl(\frac{c*d}b\Bigr)*C_B$$
$$B =Y+d*C_B$$

...where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ are constants. While I see how to get $C_R$ from the formula for $R$ and, similarly, $C_B$ from $B$, I don't really know how to rearrange formula for $Y$ so that it gives $G$ precisely as in the formula above.

Here's what I have so far:

$$Y=aR+bG+cB$$

I subtract $bG$ from both sides and replace $R$ and $B$ with $C_R$ and $C_B$...

$$Y-bG=aC_R+cC_B$$

...then I subtract $Y$...:

$$-bG=(aC_R+cC_B)-Y$$
...followed by dividing by $-b$...:

$$G=\frac{-Y+(aC_R+cC_B)}{-b}$$

...and I'm not really sure what to do next.

I probably shouldn't be playing around with such things while being bad at math, but my curiosity is killing me, and I'm more than willing to make a fool of myself if it means I'll get a few tips on how to proceed from here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The mistake here is going from $Y = aR+bG+cB$ to $Y - bG = aC_R + cC_B$ without plugging in the correct relations between $R$ and $C_R$ as well as $B$ and $C_B$. If you use $R = Y+eC_R$ and $B=Y+dC_B$, the rest should proceed just fine. And as a sidenote: if I'm not mistaken, there is an additional constraint that $a + b + c = 1$. You'll need this to get the final expression for $G$.

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction! I assume it should look something like this, then: $$Y=a*(Y+eC_R)+bG+c*(Y+dC_B)$$

This leads me to the final form that looks like this:

$$G=\frac{(aY+aeC_R+cY+cdC_B)-Y}{-b}$$

Is this ok, or did I make a mistake along the way?

Comment: Yep, looks good to me.

Comment: I got this formula, which is close to the original, but still a bit different:
$$G=\frac{-Y}{-b}+\frac{a*Y}{-b}+\frac{a*e}{-b}*C_R+\frac{c*d}{-b}*C_B$$

Not sure if splitting the fraction is the right thing to do here.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a $\frac{cY}{-b}$ term in there?

Comment: Whoops, you're right! I would really appreciate it if you could give me a little nudge yet again, as now I have $$G=\frac{-Y}{-b}+\frac{aY}{-b}+\frac{cY}{-b}...$$ (the rest is same as in the previous comment) and I'm not really sure what to do with those terms.

Comment: Not too familiar with YCbCr myself, but a glance at the equations here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#YCbCr) suggests that there is an additional constraint on $a$, $b$, and $c$, namely that $a + b + c = 1$. Using this, you could simplify your equation further by noticing that $-1 + a + c = -b$.

Comment: I've got it now, thank you so much @octave! Your trick with $-b=-1+a+c$ worked wonders, I ended up with this:
$$G=\frac{-Y+aY+cY}{-1+a+c}...$$
$$G=\frac{Y(-1+a+c)}{-1+a+c}...$$
and finally:
$$G=Y+\frac{a*e}{-b}*C_R+\frac{c*d}{-b}*C_B$$
which is same as the original, after subtracting instead of adding.

Should I make an official answer or can I just leave it all in the comments?

Comment: Looks great! Might be helpful to make an official answer and accept it just so that this can be marked as answered + closed and saved for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so step by step:

$$Y=aR+bG+cB\quad$$

subtract $bG$ from both sides and replace $R$ with $Y+e*C_R$ and $B$ with $Y+d*D_B$...

$$Y-bG=a*(Y+e*C_R)+c*(Y+d*C_B)$$

...expand the parentheses...

$$Y-bG=aY+aeC_R+cY+cdC_B$$

...subtract $Y$ from both sides...

$$-bG=(aY+aeC_R+cY+cdC_B)-Y$$

...then divide by $-b$...

$$G=\frac{(aY+aeC_R+cY+cdC_B)-Y}{-b}$$

...now we can rearrange stuff a bit...

$$G=\frac{-Y+aY+cY}{-b}+\frac{a*e}{-b}*C_R+\frac{c*d}{-b}*C_B$$

...now let's simplify the first term, keeping in mind that $a+b+c=1$. That means that $-b=-1+a+c$

$$G=\frac{-Y+aY+cY}{-1+a+c}+\frac{a*e}{-b}*C_R+\frac{c*d}{-b}*C_B$$

Let's factor out $Y$ in the numerator...

$$G=\frac{Y(-1+a+c)}{-1+a+c}+\frac{a*e}{-b}*C_R+\frac{c*d}{-b}*C_B$$

...which, after cancelling the common factor leaves us with:

$$G=Y+\frac{a*e}{-b}*C_R+\frac{c*d}{-b}*C_B$$

...and we're almost home, we just need to subtract instead of adding:

$$G=Y-\Bigl(\frac{a*e}{b}\Bigr)*C_R-\Bigl(\frac{c*d}{b}\Bigr)*C_B$$

...which takes us to the final form of the formula for calculating the green channel.

Thanks again for all the help @octave!